# Intuition behind continuously differentiable functions vs all differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, intuition

The function $x\neq 0 \mapsto x^2 \sin(1/x), x = 0 \mapsto 0$ is differentiable but not continuously differentiable, whereas $x\neq 0 \mapsto x^3 \sin(1/x), x = 0 \mapsto 0$ is continuously differentiable.  This is easy to prove.

Can we explain the *intuition* behind that? Both functions are continuous and, as they approach zero, decreasing amplitude towards zero and increasing frequency without limit.  Graphing, they both look near zero like smooth lines with ripples.  What observable property or natural characteristic makes one have a continuous derivative and one not?

We can expand this question more broadly: Differentiable functions are explained as functions where small changes in the input have proportional  changes in the output, or functions which have unique tangents.  What is the intuitive explanation of a *continuously* differentiable function?

Comment: This is one of those cases where I feel intuition is not something we are given, rather it is developed/acquired/adapted to what is correct after some practice and experience. Also, just sketching graphs of the function willy-wonka won’t tell you the fine properties of the function (e.g the properties of the derivatives). The extra power of $x$ adds that bit of regularity and it hides the bad behavior of $1/x$ after it is differentiated.

Comment: The only times I’ve found pictures helpful in these scenarios is if there’s a jump-discontinuity involved, because those are “visible” on paper (atleast if the jump is large enough to be seen on plots). Otherwise it’s hard to “see” properties from the graphs; you just gain some familiarity with the behavior of various functions.

Comment: I like to think as follows: as you say, for differentiable functions you can define in a unique way tangent lines to its graph. For continuously differentiable functions we have the additional property that tangent lines to nearby points are 'similar', that is, their slopes are close to each other. For differentiable functions, you can have abrupt changes in the slope of the tangent line of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with trying to answer a question like this intuitively is that the answer depends too much on calculation.

It's not enough to observe that the curve wiggles ever faster and faster as it approaches $x = 0,$ or that the peaks get squeezed down toward the $x$-axis. The question really is how steep the slope of the "wiggles" remain after getting squeezed down. And it's very hard to know that without actually doing some derivatives.

We can start by observing that when $x \neq 0,$
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)
 = -\frac{\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)}{x^2}.
$$

It's clear that while this derivative crosses zero infinitely many times as we approach
$x = 0,$ the $\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)$ part of it keeps hitting values of $1$ and $-1,$ so when we divide by $x^2$ we have a sequence of peaks that grow very, very fast.

Intuitively, you might thing that by multiplying by a large enough power of $x,$ we can proportionally reduce those peaks. That is not precisely true, but we can do close enough.

When we multiply $\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$ by a power of $x,$ we can use the multiplication rule to find the derivative when $x \neq 0$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} x^n \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)
 &= \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} x^n\right) \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)
    + x^n \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)  \\
 &=  n x^{n-1} \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)
     + x^n \left(-\frac{\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)}{x^2}\right)  \\
 &=  n x^{n-1} \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)
     - x^{n-2} \cos\left(\frac 1x\right).
\end{align}

Now we have **two** functions, $\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$ and
$\cos\left(\frac 1x\right),$ that are alternately hitting either $1$ or $-1,$
but the only one we really have to worry about is $\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)$
because it is only multiplied by $x^{n-2},$ whereas $\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$
is multiplied by $x^{n-1}$ which goes to zero faster.
For very small $x$ we're going to be looking at a derivative that is almost all
$- x^{n-2} \cos\left(\frac 1x\right).$

If $n = 2$ this term comes out to $\cos\left(\frac 1x\right),$ so the derivative is not going to converge to anything as $x \to 0,$ and therefore it can't converge to zero as would be required to make the derivative continuous at $x = 0.$
But if $n > 2$ we get $-x^k \cos\left(\frac 1x\right)$ for $k > 0,$
which implies that $x^k \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and therefore (by the Squeeze Theorem, which I think is fairly intuitive), the derivative goes to zero as well.

Note that this even works for non-integer powers as long as we avoid a negative base,
for example,
$$ 
f(x) = \begin{cases}\lvert x\rvert^n \sin\left(\frac 1x\right) & x\neq 0, \\
0 & x = 0.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I've generally found that once I master the calculations, they coalesce into a unified concept.  "Continuous" = sufficiently small change in input yields arbitrarily small change in output.  "Differentiable" = arbitrarily close to a linear function over a sufficiently small interval. I can see why $sin 1/x$ fails both and $x sin 1/x$ meets the first but not the second and why $x^2 sin 1/x$ meets both.  I'd like to do something similar for "continuously differentiable".

Comment: For "continuously differentiable," you need any sufficiently small change in input to yield a sufficiently small change in the linear function that the function is close to. So that's at least two overlapping sets of "sufficiently small changes" that you have to consider simultaneously. If you have a formula for the derivative, however, one set of "small changes" is already baked into the derivative, so you have only one set of small changes to look at.

Comment: So I find it very difficult (if not impossible) to look at just a graph of $x^3\sin(1/x)$ and "see" how the slopes of the linear approximations converge to zero as $x\to 0,$ but if I compute and graph the derivative it is very easy to see. And that's basically what this answer is about.